# Проблема в работе python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вчера захожу в командную строку в windows 7 (с помощью нее обычно запускаю файлы в python 3). Пишу "python" и cmd пишет, мол ""python" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом", до этого ставил галочку "add to path". Ладно, решил переустановить его. Сделал это, все работало хорошо. Сегодня та же ситуация. Даже если просто перезагрузить пк получается то же самое. Версия python 3.7.4. Помогите! Что делать?

Comment: Что-то на вашем компьютере сбрасывает настройки переменных окружения при перезагрузке. Дело тут не в Python'е.

Comment: И что мне делать?

Comment: Искать что это может быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас все работает хорошо. У меня был скачан еще один терминал Hyper, я его удалил, прочистил все остаточные файлы с помощью Ccleaner. Переустановил python в кастомный path, вроде все ок.